# Best practice for developing app extensions in iOS 8 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

I'm wondering what the best practices are when it comes to developing app extensions now during the beta of iOS 8. What I mean is that since XCode 5 doesn't support the entitlements and the targets required for an app extension (App groups, widget target etc) and XCode 6 doesn't support submitting to the appstore, is there a good way to make sure that we can both develop and deploy to the App Store, compile the old project etc?

Of course there is the SCM approach with just creating a branch but I'm wondering if there is any way to solve this in XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that creating a duplicate target is the best way, thereby keeping the old target for old Xcode and using the new target for debugging the extension.